# Flutter Textformfield how to call onSubmitted or onEditingComplete on focus loss

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, textformfield

in my app I have an list view with many textformfields.
I use this keyboard so that the user is only able to enter numbers. However, this keyboard does not have an Enter button or something similar.
[image]

Now I want to call onSubmitted or onEditingComplete if the user closes the keyboard or rather on focus loss. I don't want to use onChanged because this cases to many traffic in firestore.

Atm I use the following code to close the keyboard.

```
        return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.unfocus();
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

          }
        },
```

Is there a possible way to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using the `onSaved` property. Wrap the `TextFormField` in a form (if it isn't already) and call save on the form in your `GestureDetector`'s `onTap` function.